# Apps using the camera API crash after taking a picture on an iPhone 4S running iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, camera

Ever since I updated to iOS 7 in June, I have been having issues using the camera on my phone in apps other than the default Camera app. Regardless of settings, using my camera in any non-Apple app (such as Instagram or Tumblr) will result in that particular app crashing immediately. I have tried everything to remedy the issue short of a full restore on my phone. I'm convinced it's some sort of low memory or high CPU utilization issue, since iOS 7 seems to be much more taxing on my phone's resources than iOS 6 was. Is there some way to fix this issue without simply buying a newer, faster iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting always fixes the problem for me.

As for permanent solutions, haven't tried this myself but this comment has a possible solution (pre-iOS 7 however iOS users have reported success):  http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/how-to/how-to-fix-iphone-camera-roll-crash-and-photos-turned-to-other-in-itunes/#comment-347059180

Answer (score 1):

A full restore of your phone might be needed if you aren't keen to clear out the camera roll of all photos.

These crashes are not unheard of, but they also are not affecting most of the devices in the wild.

You could probably reset your camera roll following this thread and avoid having to start over with a full wipe of the device:

- [How can I reset the camera roll to photo IMG_0001.jpg on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88250/how-can-i-reset-the-camera-roll-to-photo-img-0001-jpg-on-ios)