# Reset camera roll to photo IMG_0001.jpg -- now it takes forever to get thumbnails when connecting to Mac

Tags: ios, photos

I followed the steps at this article ([How can I reset the camera roll to photo IMG_0001.jpg on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88250/how-can-i-reset-the-camera-roll-to-photo-img-0001-jpg-on-ios/434586#434586)) and it seemed to work, but now when I connect to my Mac to download photos, it takes SUPER long for ImageCapture.app to generate thumbnails for my photos. And it cannot download the photos until the thumbnails are all shown. Is there something that can be done to speed that up?